# LWUIT can't kill connection request

Tags: java-me, connection, lwuit, progress

Well, I have download an image from network using LWUI ImageDownloadService. While download progress, a Progress Dialog display. I want to stop downloading by pressing Cancel command. But it still downloading. What can i do to stop the download?

My code below

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
if (evt.getSource() == okCommand) {
    final Form resultForm = new Form("Result");
    resultForm.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    resultForm.show();
    Label mLabel = new Label();
    ImageDownloadService img = new ImageDownloadService("http://datastore04.rediff.com/h1500-w1500/thumb/69586A645B6D2A2E3131/s47kscdm7r4pjx05.D.0.Happy-Valentines-Day-Wallpaper-Image.jpg", mLabel);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(img);
    resultForm.addComponent(mLabel);
    Progress progress = new Progress("Loading", img);
    progress.setDisposeOnCompletion(true);
    progress.show();
}
```

I have uploaded picture [here](http://i8.upanh.com/2013/0702/07/56604752.process.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lwuit Network Connection Timeout issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416994/lwuit-network-connection-timeout-issue)

Comment: can't set timeout, can't stop connection?

Comment: Look this reference. This is my answer   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966033/how-to-handle-network-thread-calls-and-wait-progress-in-j2me/13969115#13969115

Comment: i try your menthod. but it still downloading

Comment: J2ME doesn't have a way to stop a connection or define a timeout period for a connection. What we tried to do with the connection request is kill the thread making the connection which is something that may or may not work but its pretty much the only workaround for this inherent design flaw in J2ME.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is... put this code in a `Thread` and in the `Command` logic stop this thread.